# EC2 Snapshot LifeCycle Policy with Custom Retention Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

We have a back up rules to keep snapshots of the instance as per below rules:

1. One snapshot every day for the most recent 7 days and
2. One snapshot every weekend for the most recent 4 weeks and
3. One snapshot every month-end for the most recent 12 months.

So in total, there will be 7 + (4-1) + (12-1) = 21 copies required at any point in time.

However, the existing EC2 snapshot lifecycle policy does not seem flexible to retain my back up copies as per above rules. Hence, I was thinking about using Lambda function or step functions. But the lifecycle policy will override the Lambda function, won't it?

Any ideas how this can be achieved from a solution architecture perspective?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we managed to achieve this by creating 3 separate lifecycle policies.

1. Create a snapshot once a day, and keep it for 7 days.
2. Do the same every Sunday, and keep it for 30 days.
3. Another snapshot every 1st day of the month, and keep it for 365 days.